# Updating pandas DataFrame by key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of historical stock trades.  The frame has columns like ['ticker', 'date', 'cusip', 'profit', 'security_type'].  Initially:

```
trades['cusip'] = np.nan
trades['security_type'] = np.nan
```

I have historical config files that I can load into frames that have columns like ['ticker',  'cusip', 'date', 'name', 'security_type', 'primary_exchange'].

I would like to UPDATE the trades frame with the cusip and security_type from config, but only where the ticker and date match.

I thought I could do something like:

```
pd.merge(trades, config, on=['ticker', 'date'], how='left')
```

But that doesn't update the columns, it just adds the config columns to trades.

The following works, but I think there has to be a better way.  If not, I will probably do it outside of pandas.

```
for date in trades['date'].unique():
    config = get_config_file_as_df(date)
    ## config['date'] == date
    for ticker in trades['ticker'][trades['date'] == date]:
        trades['cusip'][ 
                           (trades['ticker'] == ticker)
                         & (trades['date']   == date)
                       ] \
            = config['cusip'][config['ticker'] == ticker].values[0]

        trades['security_type'][ 
                           (trades['ticker'] == ticker)
                         & (trades['date']   == date)
                       ] \
            = config['security_type'][config['ticker'] == ticker].values[0]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose you have this setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as DT

nan = np.nan

trades = pd.DataFrame({'ticker' : ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AAPL'],
                       'date' : pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods = 4), 
                       'cusip' : [nan, nan, 100, nan]
                       })
trades = trades.set_index(['ticker', 'date'])
print(trades)
#                    cusip
# ticker date             
# IBM    2000-01-01    NaN
# MSFT   2000-01-02    NaN
# GOOG   2000-01-03    100  # <-- We do not want to overwrite this
# AAPL   2000-01-04    NaN

config = pd.DataFrame({'ticker' : ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AAPL'],
                       'date' : pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods = 4),
                       'cusip' : [1,2,3,nan]})
config = config.set_index(['ticker', 'date'])

# Let's permute the index to show `DataFrame.update` correctly matches rows based on the index, not on the order of the rows.
new_index = sorted(config.index)
config = config.reindex(new_index)    
print(config)
#                    cusip
# ticker date             
# AAPL   2000-01-04    NaN
# GOOG   2000-01-03      3
# IBM    2000-01-01      1
# MSFT   2000-01-02      2
```

Then you can update NaN values in `trades` with values from `config` using the `DataFrame.update` method. Note that `DataFrame.update` matches rows based on indices (which is why `set_index` was called above).

```
trades.update(config, join = 'left', overwrite = False)
print(trades)

#                    cusip
# ticker date             
# IBM    2000-01-01      1
# MSFT   2000-01-02      2
# GOOG   2000-01-03    100 # If overwrite = True, then 100 is overwritten by 3.
# AAPL   2000-01-04    NaN
```